# How to get a function values inside of function in PHP?

Tags: php

How to get a values in function of inner function in php?

```
<?php

function rating($val){

}

function cal($val){
}

echo rating(cal('q1'));
echo rating('q1');
echo cal('q1');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
function rating($val) {
    return cal($val);
}
function cal($val) {
    return do_something_with_value($val);
}
echo rating('q1');
```

Another option would be something like that:

```
<?php
function rating($val) {
    return do_something_else_with_value($val);
}
function cal($val) {
    return do_something_with_value($val);
}
echo rating(cal('q1'));
```

When asking a question it is often a good idea to explain *what* you are trying to do instead of *how* you think you might be able to do it.

Comment: then how to get a single function? like `echo rating('q1');`

Comment: Sorry, as said above: your question is extremely vague, we do not really know what you ask. I would say that the first optin I posted is the answer to your comment here, but I cannot really know, since you do not really what it is you are looking for! What does "how to get a single function" mean? How does one "get" a function? By defining and using it is the obvious answer. But I doubt that is what you ask, so what is your _real_ question?